# MariaDB MySQL shows have_ssl disabled when certs are installled

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb

Trying to enabled SSL on my mariadb-server. I have followed the official mariadb docs to generate a ca-key ca-cert server-key server-cert. My machine is a debian 9 kvm vps with mariadb **10.1.37**

When I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl';` as root I get this output:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                          |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | NO                             |
| have_ssl            | DISABLED                       |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath          |                                |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher          |                                |
| ssl_crl             |                                |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                |
| ssl_key             | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem  |
| version_ssl_library | YaSSL 2.4.4                    |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I have tried re-creating the certificates multiple times including with different common names. The certificates are installed under `/etc/mysql/ssl/`

I have also tried starting `mysqld` with the `--ssl` option, and adding `ssl=on` in the config. I cannot find any more information related to this as I have YASSL instead of openssl since mariadb is now compiled with YASSL by default unless I am missing something, and YASSL doesn't work with my keys?

How I created the certificates and keys:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem

openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365000 \
      -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem

openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365000 \
      -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem

openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem

openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 365000 \
      -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 \
      -out server-cert.pem
```

My 50-server.cnf file:

```
    #
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
#log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = exclude_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
#ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
ssl=on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

Comment: It looks like a permission issue for the certs. chmod should be 644 /etc/mysql/ssl/*. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

After a few hours of screwing around I  figured out that mysql was unable to read the key file. I set the group of the files to mysql.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/ssl/
```

Comment: Reece is right, `chown -R mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/ssl/` is the solution. It's odd that mysql can't report that he cannot read the key file.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same behaviour on RedHat's family.

Turn's out that SELinux blocked the have_ssl because the certs are not in the home of mysql/mariadb.

You just have to move the files to the mysql user's home which you can find with the following command:

```
grep mysql /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{ print $6}'
```

Comment: `You just have to move the files.` - ok, nice, but how's about to tell what you have done exactly?? :-)

Comment: My certs was in a path of a user instead of the mysql user's home. I update my previous post to add how to find the hole path.

Comment: Copy, not move.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem. I used OpenSSL to generate my key and it created a PKCS#8 file which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[base64 key material]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It appears that the server is expecting a PKCS#1 file, which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[base64 key material]
----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In order to convert from one form to the other, you can use `openssl`:

```
$ openssl rsa -in /path/to/pkcs8 > /path/to/pkcs1
```

Once I did this, I was able to start my server with SSL enabled.

Newer versions of OpenSSL use PKCS#8 by default while older versions used PKCS#1 files by default (for RSA keys). That would explain why guides written (and working!) several years back can cause problems now.

MariaDB really needs to support PKCS#8 key files. I'm sure this wouldn't be a problem if my MariaDB had been built against OpenSSL, but it's using YaSSL just like the original poster.